How to create nested list columns in polars
In R with tidyverse, using group_by() and nest() I can create list columns that are very useful for fitting models to multiple datasets.
How can I achieve the same outcome in polars in Python, such that each element of the data column is a small dataframe?
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("dataset_id", [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("day", [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("recipe", [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("cum_trials", [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("cum_events", [644, 1287, 643, 1262, 645, 1312, 655, 1301], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("cum_rate", [0.644, 0.643, 0.643, 0.619, 0.645, 0.667, 0.655, 0.646], dtype=pl.Float64),
    ]
)

In R/tidyverse the syntax I want to replicate is
df_list <- df |> group_by(dataset_id, day) |> nest()

df_list


df_list$data[[1]]



If all sub-datasets share column, why not just have one large frame (with dataset_id to differentiate between sub-datasets) and fit the model to each group defined by dataset_id?

import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,1,2,2], 
    'b':[3,4,5,6], 
    'c':[7,8,9,0],
    'string': ["hey", "you", "kids", "go"]
})

df.with_columns(my_list_col = pl.struct('b', 'string'))

a   b   c   string  my_list_col
i64 i64 i64 str     struct[2]
1   3   7   "hey"   {3,"hey"}
1   4   8   "you"   {4,"you"}
2   5   9   "kids"  {5,"kids"}
2   6   0   "go"    {6,"go"}

df.group_by('a').agg(list_col = pl.struct(cs.integer()))

a   list_col
i64 list[struct[2]]
1   [{3,"hey"}, {4,"you"}]
2   [{5,"kids"}, {6,"go"}]

